# Create a tag for the [deepstream.io] library

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Just came across the very new, neat library [deepstream.io](http://deepstream.io/). The authors are very helpful and have responded with a lot of good answers to my questions via email. I feel a lot of people could benefit from the information I've received, but I can't create a [deepstream.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deepstream.io) tag on SO because of my insufficient reputation.

I definitely feel a new tag is warranted. Could anyone do this for me?

> Deepstream is a Node server that allows clients to sync data, whether they're browsers or mobile applications. It has a caching layer, and supports event-based messaging and RPC.

-Alex R. Young

Comment: Do you have a question that needs the tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024304/retrieving-a-list-of-records-in-deepstream-io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added that tag to the question, and added the quote from this question to that tag.